# Java- I am not getting output from my for loop and if statements

Tags: java

Could someone explain why I am getting no output from this program. I am trying to create a morse code translator for digits using a for loop and if statements but nothing appears and I put in the morse code I want to have translated.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class MorseDecoder extends ConsoleProgram
{
public void run()
{
    String morseDig = ""; 
    int digit = 0;
    String morse = readLine("Please enter the morse code: ");

    for (int i = 0; i == morse.length(); i += 5)
    {
        if (morseDig == ".----"){
            digit = 1;
        }
            else if(morseDig == "..---"){
                digit = 2;
                System.out.println(digit);
            }
            else if(morseDig == "...--"){
                digit = 3;
            }
            else if(morseDig == "....-"){
                digit = 4;
            }
            else if(morseDig == "....."){
                digit = 5;
            }
            else if(morseDig == "-...."){
                digit = 6;
            }
            else if(morseDig == "--..."){
                digit = 7;
            }    
            else if(morseDig == "---.."){
                digit = 8;
            }
            else if(morseDig == "----."){
                digit = 9;
            }
            else if(morseDig == "-----"){
                digit = 0;
            }
                else{
                    println("NaN");
                }
    }
}

//~ Methods ...............................................................

}
```

the NaN at the end is used when the morse code has no numeric translation.

Comment: morseDig is set to an empty string at the top, and not changed thereafter. Every comparison will fail. Not that it matters because the for loop runs while `i` is equal to `morse.length()`, which it will never be because it's initialised to zero, so the loop never runs.

Answer (score 2):

`".....".equals(morseDig)` etc on down the line.  Comparing `Strings` with `==` in `Java` doesn't do what you think it does.

You're also not actually taking user input and setting `morseDig` anywhere.  Your `for` loop isn't doing what you think because `morse.length()` is returning `0` and you're not executing the body even once.